# Replace nth line below the searched pattern in a file

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I needed to replace 4th line (which contain pattern Y) after a search pattern (say X) in a file. Please note pattern Y is used elsewhere too. So I can't replace it directly. Also note on the 4th line there is only one word Y.
Is there any scripting command possible that can do with ease? May be "awk" useful but not sure how to use it exactly.

ex: Pattern to search X in a file.
In file we have say

```
X,
C,
D,
Y,
A,
```

Now I needed to replace Y which is on 4th line to say `B,`.

Answer (score 10):

For low numbers of lines:

```
sed '/X/ { n; n; n; s/Y/B/; }' filename
```

This is fairly straightforward:

```
/X/ {      # If the current line matches /X/
  n        # fetch the next line (printing the current one unchanged)
  n        # and the next line
  n        # and the next line
  s/Y/B/   # and in that line, replace Y with B.
}
```

Since this becomes somewhat unwieldy for large numbers, you may want to consider using awk for such cases:

```
awk 'NR == marker { sub(/Y/, "B") } /X/ { marker = NR + 3 } 1' filename
```

That is:

```
NR == marker { sub(/Y/, "B") }  # if the current line is marked, substitute
/X/ { marker = NR + 3 }         # if the current line matches /X/, mark the one
                                # that comes three lines later for substitution
1                               # print
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this in awk:

```
awk '/X/ || f == 1 && sub(/Y,/, "B,") { ++f } 1' file
```

This sets the flag `f` to 1 (or *true*) when the pattern `/X/` is matched. When `f` is true and `sub` returns a *true* value (which it does when it performs a substitution), then `s` is set to true and `f` back to false. This means that `f` is only true once, so only one occurrence of `Y,` will be substituted.

Testing it out on a slightly different example to the one you showed in your question:

```
$ cat file
Y,
A,
X,
C,
D,
Y,
A,
X,
Y,
$ awk '/X/ && !s { f = 1 } f && sub(/Y,/, "B,") { s = 1; f = 0 } 1' file
Y,
A,
X,
C,
D,
B,
A,
X,
Y,
```

As you can see, only the `Y,` after the first `X` has been replaced. It doesn't matter how many lines there are between the `X` and the `Y,`, or if there are more than one `X` before the first `Y,`.

---

If you want to substitute all occurrences of `Y,` after `X` appears, then you can simplify the code:

```
awk '/X/ { f = 1 } f { sub(/Y,/, "B,") } 1' file
```

As before, this sets the flag `f` when `/X/` has been found. It then performs the substitution every time `Y,` is found from that point onward.

Testing it out, using the same input as above:

```
$ awk '/X/ && !s { f = 1 } f { sub(/Y,/, "B,") } 1' file
Y,
A,
X,
C,
D,
B,
A,
X,
B,
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. However it replaces at only one place. What if needed to replace at all the places in the file? I am not very much aware of "awk". So please excuse.

Answer (score 2):

another `awk` alternative, similar to Tom Fenech's, but perhaps easier to read

```
 awk 'x&&!s{s=sub(/Y/,"B")} /X/{x=1} 1'
```

if in x and not substituted, substitute; set context to x, when match X; print. Above will replace the first instance.  If you want to replace only on line n, you can do the following variation.

```
awk 'x&&c++==2{sub(/Y/,"B")} /X/{x=1} 1'
```

this will replace the third line (counter starts at zero) after first X match.  Or, if you want to see "3" in the script,

```
awk 'x&&++c==3{sub(/Y/,"B")} /X/{x=1} 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

In `sed` a relative address offset (counted from `/REGEX/`) you can achieve with:

```
sed '/X/,+3 {/X/,+2! s/Y/B/}' filename
```

which means a 4-lines range (from `/X/` to `X+3`) from which in curly braces `{}` we subtract a sub-range smaller by 1 line (from `/X/` to `X+2`) by adding negation `!` after that. Effectively we pass only exact lines we're interested in (`X+3`) for further processing (substitution in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to use through mapping key in vim

```
:map z n4j^cwY<esc>
```

Explanation:

- `n` is next
- `4j` is 4 lines below
- `cw` is change word
- `Y` is pattern name